# I would like to remove form entry with something like this. Is there other nicer way to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code and it is working but, i am looking for a nicer and cleaner way to do this.
I like to remove entered text from my form inputs.

I have done the same thing for each entry of my forms, can anyone help me find a better way to tho this?

Thanks.

```js
// clear text user email
    if($('.user_email').val() === '') {
        $("#clear_user_email").hide();
    }
    $("#clear_user_email .clear_text").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.user_email').val('');
        
        if($("#clear_user_email").is(":visible")) {
            $("#clear_user_email").hide();
        }
    });
    $( ".user_email" ).keyup(function(){ 
        $("#clear_user_email").show();
    });
```

```html
<div id="user_email_P" class="form-group has-feedback">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope red"></i>
    </span>
    <input name="user_email" type="email" class="form-control user_email" placeholder="email@address.com">
  </div>
  <div class="remove_button">
    <div id="clear_user_email">
      <a href="#" class="clear_text">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" style="top: 1px;"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could do as Wolff suggested with:

```html
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

but I have to many form inputs on my form.
the form submit with ajax

Comment: Do you even need javascript? `<input type="reset" value="Clear">` or `<button type="reset">Clear</button>`

Comment: So what is expected behaviour, clear all inputs or only specific one??? Not clear what you are asking. `but I have to many form inputs on my form. the form submit with ajax` Using `reset` will clear **ALL**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to clear all the fields just individual ones, maybe try this...

```
$(function(){
    $('#myForm input').each(function(){

        //Using your current DOM structure
        var t = $(this);
        var c = $(t).parents(".form-group").find(".clear_text");
        var cp = $(c).parent();

        if($(t).val() === '') {
            $(cp).hide();
        }

        $(c).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(t).val('');

            if($(cp).is(":visible")){
                $(cp).hide();
            }
        });

        $(t).keyup(function(){ 
            $(cp).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you David, it dose exactly what I want. It works! Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know the reason but, when I clear once the input text, it don't works the second time without page refresh, so i changed $(this).hide(); into $(cp).hide(); and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button called 'Clear'. On click, set all fields to ''.

Comment: There is already a reset() method for FORM or the reset button: `<input type="reset" value="Reset">`

Comment: @A.Wolff or even that. Tie the reset() to the button and done.

Comment: But i'm not sure this is what OP is looking for. EDIT: rereading question, i think ya, it is what he is looking for indeed

Comment: Well it looks like he is clearing the fields in a form so this solution would do that in 2 lines of code for all fields.

Comment: I could do that, but there are to many inputs on my form. It works with this code, but i have to do the same for each form input.

Comment: No the reset should clear all fields at once. Why do you have to do it for every field? Or do you want to clear specific inputs? If it is specific inputs than there is no easy way of doing it, you would have to create a way to clear them individually.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your expected behaviour, you could use to clear all inputs:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```